# Keys in the keyboard are not functioning in an interactive script!

Tags: bash, readline

I am using this code in bash to make my script interactive. What I mean by `interactive` is to let the script ask me questions such as what is the path to my data:

```
#!/bin/bash -ef
read userInput
if [[ -n "$mypath" ]]
then
datadir=$mypath 
fi
printf "YOUR PATH TO DATA IS: $datadir  ";
```

I have the following issues:

1. The previous code is unable to display the words perfectly, especially
   when I use `TAB` key to complete the words or the `right/left arrows` to go through the letters. For example, if I made a mistake in my writing to the path, then when I want to correct this mistake by using any key like `Home`, `End`, `arrows left/right`, etc., these keys are not functioning well
2. If my entry is `empty` ( I mean by *empty* no path to the data or just a blank field), I want the code to ask me again to enter the path or to abort the process and exit.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: How should the script know that you have _made a mistake in my entry_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ((1)) ; do
  echo please define path:
  read input
  echo is $input ok [y/n/abort]?
  read answer
  case $answer in
    [yY]|[Yy][Ee][Ss]*)
      path=$input
      break
      ;;
    [Aa][Bb][Oo][Rr][Tt])
      exit
      ;;
    [Nn]|[Nn][Oo])
      ;;
    *)
      echo invalid input, please try again
      ;;
  esac
done
```

in other words: an infinite loop over a `case` statement that only breaks if the user verifies the entry. Of course you can also introduce a check whether this path is actually existing before even issuing the `case` feedback loop.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I want in my second question but how can I deal with problem that I introduced in my first question. Why the words and letters are not  showing when I use Tab key

Comment: @goro `read -e answer`

Comment: @Sparhawk. Woww man. Thanks a lot! YOU ARE GENIUS :)))

Comment: @goro TBH I just searched the web for `bash read input tab completion`. :)

Comment: @Sparhawk. Also Genius. I have been looking for it for a whole of two days. Thanks!!